# My python program in numba is not speeding up

Tags: python, numpy, numba

My program written for calculating magnetisation takes more time for computation. So I switched to `numba`.But I could not see any speed increase. Could anyone help me. I am trying to run this code in a 24 core processor.

```
import time  
import datetime
import numpy as np from math 
import pi
import numba from numba 
import jit,njit,double,vectorize,float64,int64
import time 

 #%% parameters for the calculations
    mu0 = 4e-7 * pi
        h_planck=6.58212e-4# mev*ns
        mub=5.78e-2#meV/T
        g=2
        s=2
        T=2.0 #K
       dt=0.5e-5
       Kb=8.6e-2
       Kjt=1.5
       gamma =(g*mub)/h_planck #1/(T*ns) 
       alpha = 1
       mus=mub*g*s
eA=np.array([-np.sqrt(2.0/3.0),0.0,-np.sqrt(1.0/3.0)])
eB=np.array([-np.sqrt(1.0/6.0),-np.sqrt(1.0/2.0),np.sqrt(1.0/3.0)])
eC=np.array([-np.sqrt(1.0/6.0),np.sqrt(1.0/2.0),np.sqrt(1.0/3.0)])
@njit
def dot(S1,eA,eB,eC):
    result1=0.0
    result2=0.0
    result3=0.0
    for i in range(3):
        result1 += S1[i]*eA[i]
        result2 += S1[i]*eB[i]
        result3 += S1[i]*eC[i]

    return result1,result2,result3
@njit
def jahnteller1(S1):
    global Kjt
    M,N,O=dot(S1,eA,eB,eC)
    P,Q,R=M**5,N**5,O**5
    X=3.0*Kjt*((eA*P+eB*Q+eC*R))
    return X/mus
@njit
def thermal1():
    mu, sigma = 0, 1 # mean and standard deviation
    G = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 3)
    Hth1=G*np.sqrt((2*alpha*Kb*T)/(gamma*mus*dt))
    return Hth1
#%% calculation of effective field
@njit
def h_eff(B,S1,eH):
    Heff1 = eH*B+jahnteller1(S1)+thermal1()
    return  Heff1
#%% evaluating cross products
@njit
def cross1(S1,heff1):
    result1=np.zeros(3)
    a1, a2, a3 = S1[0], S1[1], S1[2]
    b1, b2, b3 = heff1[0], heff1[1],heff1[2]
    result1[0] = a2 * b3 - a3 * b2
    result1[1] = a3 * b1 - a1 * b3
    result1[2] = a1 * b2 - a2 * b1
    return result1
@njit
def cross2(S1,X):
    result2=np.zeros(3)
    a1, a2, a3 = S1[0],S1[1],S1[2]
    c1, c2, c3 = X[0],X[1],X[2]
    result2[0] = a2 * c3 - a3 * c2
    result2[1] = a3 * c1 - a1 * c3
    result2[2] = a1 * c2 - a2 * c1
    return result2
#%% Main function to calculate the Spin S1 by calculating the effective field
 @njit
def llg(S1,dt, B,eH):
    global gamma,alpha
    N_init = int(5)
    for i in range(N_init):
        heff1 = h_eff(B,S1,eH)
        X=cross1(S1,heff1)
        Y=cross2(S1,X)
        dS1dt = - gamma/(1+alpha**2) * X \
           - alpha*gamma/(1+alpha**2) * Y
        S1 += dt * dS1dt
        normS1 = np.sqrt(S1[0]*S1[0]+S1[1]*S1[1]+S1[2]*S1[2])
        S1 = S1/normS1
    Savg=np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
    Navg=N_init*10
    for i in range(Navg):
        heff1 = h_eff(B,S1,eH)
        X=cross1(S1,heff1)
        Y=cross2(S1,X)
        dS1dt = - gamma/(1+alpha**2) * X \
           - alpha*gamma/(1+alpha**2) * Y
        S1 += dt * dS1dt
        normS1 = np.sqrt(S1[0]*S1[0]+S1[1]*S1[1]+S1[2]*S1[2])
        S1 = S1/normS1
        Savg=Savg+S1
    Savg=Savg/Navg
    return Savg  
#%% calculating dot product
@njit
def dott(S1,K):
    result=0.0
    for i in range(3):
        result += S1[i]*K[i]
    return result


 #%% initialising magn
        magn=np.zeros([25,3]) 
        Th=[]
        Ph=[]
        B=5.0
        theta=np.linspace(0.0,np.pi,5)
        phi=np.linspace(0.0,2*np.pi,5)
    for i in range(len(phi)):
        for j in range(len(theta)):
            M,N=phi[i],theta[j]
            Th.append(N)
            Ph.append(M)

#%% calling the main fuction
for i in range(25):
    magn[i][0]=Ph[i]
    magn[i][1]=Th[i]
    eH=np.array([np.sin(Th[i])*np.cos(Ph[i]),np.sin(Th[i])*np.sin(Ph[i]),np.cos(Th[i])])
    normH = np.sqrt(eH[0]*eH[0]+eH[1]*eH[1]+eH[2]*eH[2])
    eH=eH/normH
    S1=np.array([np.sin(Th[i])*np.cos(Ph[i]),np.sin(Th[i])*np.sin(Ph[i]),np.cos(Th[i])])
    S1=llg(S1,dt,B,eH)
    K=eH*B
    Z=dott(S1,K)
    E=-Z*g*mub*s
    magn[i][2]=E

#%% printing magn
print(magn)
%timeit magn
```

Comment: `magn` seems to be just an array, so when you do `%timeit magn` you are not timing any computation whatsoever.

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary memory allocations like `result2=np.zeros(3)` in the cross1 and cross2 functions. Allocate temporary arrays only once, avoid them completely or use stack arrays (can be done using intrinsics. Also avoid all uneccesary lists, where you could use a simple array instead. And most importantly get rid of all global variables.

Comment: I have tried all attempts. Its again too slow. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. You don't seem to be timing the whole operation. I'm unsure what the last `%timeit` expression gives you
2. On my machine, running the code as you have given runs in about 2.5 seconds
3. Note that the first call to a Numba function is very slow as a compiler is converting the code into llvm code. If you change @njit to @njit(cache=True) then the result gets cached and future runs do not cause compilation (until you change the function). When I do this on my machine the first run still takes 2.5 seconds but the second run finished in 0.12 seconds.
4. None of this holds a candle to running this function in pure python, which only takes 0.06 seconds.

**Why?**

The biggest reason for that in your code seems to be that you have a number of small functions which you are calling from Python inside a loop. Calling a numba function incurs overhead (which I think is worse than the overhead of calling a normal python function since there's type checking to be done). As such if your jitted functions are simple, the benefit of using them becomes negligible (or worse, you get a penalty for it). If you can change your code so that the entire logic (i.e. the main loop) are also inside a numba function it *may* become faster than pure python.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But actually it is not speeding up.

Comment: Your code is not complex enough then to really benefit from Numba. If you simply need to call it on many different inputs and throughput is the issue then consider using Multiprocessing